How to detect starting parenthesis '(' using Koltin infix function
I am building SQL where clause like expression in pure Kotlin.
I am facing problem in detecting if user has used starting parenthesis in their code or not.
I have created a working and replicable Junit test sample.
Kindly run below tests one by one.
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

class Sample {

    class Expression(private val data: String) {

        var parenthesis = 0 // Negative means '(', Positive means ')', Zero means none.

        init {
            if (data == " AND " || data == " OR ") {
                wasAndOr = true
            } else {
                wasAndOr = false
                expressions.add(this)
            }
        }

        companion object {
            val expressions = mutableListOf<Expression>()
            var wasAndOr = false
            fun create(): String {
                val builder = StringBuilder(64)
                expressions.forEach {
                    if (it.parenthesis < 0) for (i in it.parenthesis until 0) builder.append('(')
                    builder.append(it.data)
                    if (it.parenthesis > 0) for (i in 0 until it.parenthesis) builder.append(')')
                }
                return builder.toString()
            }

            fun clear() {
                expressions.clear()
            }
        }

        infix fun and(other: Expression): Expression {
            applyParenthesis(other)
            expressions.add(expressions.indexOf(other), Expression(" AND "))
            return this
        }

        infix fun or(other: Expression): Expression {
            applyParenthesis(other)
            expressions.add(expressions.indexOf(other), Expression(" OR "))
            return this
        }

        private fun applyParenthesis(exp: Expression) {
            if (wasAndOr) {
                exp.parenthesis--
                expressions.last().parenthesis++
            }
        }

        override fun toString(): String {
            return data
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testParenthesis() {
        (Expression("1") or Expression("2")) and (Expression("3") or Expression("4"))
        Assert.assertEquals("(1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 4)", Expression.create())
        Expression.clear()
    }

    @Test
    fun testWithoutParenthesis() {
        Expression("1") or Expression("2") and (Expression("3") or Expression("4"))
        Assert.assertEquals("1 OR 2 AND (3 OR 4)", Expression.create())
        Expression.clear()
    }

    @Test
    fun testParenthesisLater() {
        Expression("1") or Expression("2") and ((Expression("3") or Expression("4")) and Expression(
            "5"
        ))
        Assert.assertEquals("1 OR 2 AND ((3 OR 4) AND 5)", Expression.create())
        Expression.clear()
    }
}

My actual code is more complex.
This is just simplified version of the demo.

You cannot "detect" parentheses. That is, you cannot distinguish between A or B and C and (A or B) and C. Are you open to a different approach using expression trees? Your current approach is very error-prone.

Yeah. Kindly let me know if there is any other approach. Do you have any links to refer to? Or any sample?

It is impossible to distinguish between (A or B) and C and A or B and C. Kotlin infix functions all have the same precedence and are all left-associative. You cannot make the Kotlin compiler parse them the same way an SQL parser would parse them. If you mean A or (B and C), then write that instead.
Instead of having a global shared state expressions that you have to reset every time, have Expressions themselves form a tree structure. This can be done with a sealed hierarchy like this:
sealed interface Expression<T> {
    data class Integer(private val value: Int) : Expression<Int> {
        override fun toString() = value.toString()
    }
    data class Var<T>(private val name: String) : Expression<T> {
        override fun toString() = name
    }

    data class Equality<T>(private val left: Expression<T>, private val right: Expression<T>) : Expression<Boolean> {
        override fun toString() = "($left = $right)"
    }

    data class And(val left: Expression<Boolean>, val right: Expression<Boolean>) : Expression<Boolean> {
        override fun toString() = "($left AND $right)"
    }

    data class Or(val left: Expression<Boolean>, val right: Expression<Boolean>) : Expression<Boolean> {
        override fun toString() = "($left OR $right)"
    }
}

Note the T type parameter. This represents the type of the expression, so you don't accidentally write things like 123 AND true.
Each type of expression has its own toString implementation. By calling toString on an Expression, you end up "recursively" calling toString of each node of the tree, and as a result they create the string representation of the whole expression.
Then you can create some factory functions for these, so it looks more like a DSL.
infix fun Expression.Var<Int>.`=`(other: Int) = Expression.Equality(this, Expression.Integer(other))
// or more generally,
infix fun <T> Expression<T>.`=`(other: Expression<T>) = Expression.Equality(this, other)

infix fun Expression<Boolean>.and(other : Expression<Boolean>) = Expression.And(this, other)
infix fun Expression<Boolean>.or(other : Expression<Boolean>) = Expression.Or(this, other)

Then you can do:
val a = Expression.Var<Int>("A")
val b = Expression.Var<Int>("B")
val c = Expression.Var<Int>("C")

println(((a `=` 1) or (a `=` 2)) and ((b `=` 3) or (c `=` 4)))
// (((A = 1) OR (A = 2)) AND ((B = 3) OR (C = 4)))


Thanks @sweeper, I will give this a try and update.

Hey, I this approach also the problem remains same. If user ungroup a=1 or b=2, we will never know in our library. Try this println((a =1) or (a=2) and ((b=3) or (c= 4))). It still gives the same output.

@AzimAnsari I told you that it is impossible already, didn't I? There is no way to tell them apart. Kotlin infix functions all have the same precedence. It's Kotlin, not SQL.

@AzimAnsari Bottom line is, the users of your library needs to be aware of this and group the expressions carefully. In the example you gave, if you want and to have more precedence, it should be written as (a \=` 1) or ((a `=` 2) and ((b `=` 3) or (c `=` 4)))`.

Got it! By default, first two expressions always take precedence over others due to left to right execution.
